# Google calendar events not showing up on FullCalendar

Tags: javascript, jquery, api, calendar, fullcalendar

I am trying to get a calendar on my website that syncs with the data on my google calendar and displays it on the webpage.

To do so, I've used FullCalendar and followed the steps on the documents.
I get The calendar but its not displaying the events from googlecalendar.It's just blank.
I've got the API, the ID, and it is not set to private.

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>calendario fiscal</title>
  <!--Fullcalendar Dependencies-->
  <link href='fullcalendar/fullcalendar.css' rel='stylesheet' />
  <link href='fullcalendar/fullcalendar.print.css' rel='stylesheet' media='print'/>

  <script src='fullcalendar/gcal.js'></script>

  <!--jQuery-->
  <script src='jquery/jquery-1.9.1.min.js'></script>
  <script src='jquery/jquery-ui-1.10.2.custom.min.js'></script>

  <!--FullCalendar-->
  <script src='fullcalendar/fullcalendar.min.js'></script>

  <script type="text/javascript">

  $(document).ready(function()
  {

    var date = new Date();
    var d = date.getDate();
    var m = date.getMonth();
    var y = date.getFullYear();

    var calendar = $('#calendar').fullCalendar(
    {
      googleCalendarApiKey: 'mykey',

      header:
      {
        left: "prev,next today",
        center: "title",
        right: "month,agendaWeek,agendaDay"
      },

      defaultView: "month",

      selectable: false,
      selectHelper: false,

      events: {
            googleCalendarId: "myid"
        }

  });
    });

  </script>
</head>


  <body>
  <div id="calendar">
  </div>

  </body>
  </html>
```

/////////UPDATE////////////
Following @Victor Rocheron's suggestion, here's what I have:

```
`
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<title>calendario fiscal</title>
<link href='fullcalendar/fullcalendar.css' rel='stylesheet' />
<link href='fullcalendar/fullcalendar.print.css' rel='stylesheet' media='print'/>

<script src='fullcalendar/gcal.js'></script>
<script src='jquery/jquery-1.9.1-min.js'></script>
<script src='jquery/jquery-ui-1.10.2.custom.min.js'></script>


    <script type="text/javascript">

    function doRequest(options, printResult){
    var x = new XMLHttpRequest();
    x.open(options.method, options.url);
    x.onload = x.onerror = function(){
        printResult(
            (x.responseText || '')
        );
    };
    x.send(options.data);
    }

    (function(){
        doRequest({
            method:'GET',
            url: 'https://www.google.apis.com/calendars/myid@group.calendar.google.com/events?key=mykey',
        }, function printResult(result){

        result = JSON.parse(result);
        var i;
        var str,end;
        eventsList = {
            events: []
        }
        for(i=0;i < result.items.length;i++) {

            str = result.items[i].start.dateTime;
            end = result.items[i].end.dateTime;

            eventsList.events.push({
                "title": result.items[i].summary,
                "start":str,
                "end":end,
                "description": result.items[i].description
            });
        }

                var myEvents = eventsList.events;
                $('#calendar').fullCalendar({

                header: {
                left: 'prev,next today controle',
                center: 'title',
                right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
                },
                defaultView: 'agendaWeek',
                timezone: "Europe/Paris",
                selectable:true,
                selectHelper:true,
                minTime:"07:00:00",
                maxTime:"21:00:00",
                contentHeight: 685,
                lang: 'fr',
                select: function(start, end) {
                var title = prompt('Event Title:');
                var eventData;

                if(title) {
                eventData = {
                    title: title,
                    start: start,
                    end: end,
                    description: description
                    };
                $('#calendar').fullCalendar('renderEvent', eventData, true); //stick?=true
            }
            $('#calendar').fullCalendar('unselect');
            },
            editable:true,
            eventLimit: true, //allow "more" link when too many eventsevents: myEvents

            });

        setTimeout("$('.fc-today-button').click();", 50);



    </script>

    <style type="text/css">

        body{
            margin-top: 40px;
            text-align: center;
            font-size: 14px;
            font-family: "Lucida Grande",Helvetica,Arial,Verdana,sans-serif;
        }

        #calendar{
            width:  900px;
      height: auto;
            margin: 0 auto;
        }

    </style>

<body>
<div id="calendar">
</body>

</html>

`
```

I'm not grasping what the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an implementation I did several months ago, just replace <--YOURID--> and <--YOURKEY--> by yours and tell me if it work

https://jsfiddle.net/cw48ssyn/

Javascript :

```
function doRequest(options, printResult) {
    var x = new XMLHttpRequest();
    x.open(options.method, options.url);
    x.onload = x.onerror = function() {
      printResult(
        (x.responseText || '')
      );
    };
    x.send(options.data);
  }


 (function() {
    doRequest({
        method: 'GET',
        url: 'https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/<---YOURID-->/events?key=<--YOURKEY-->',
    }, function printResult(result) {

    result = JSON.parse(result);
    var i;
    var str,end;
    eventsList = {
        events: []
    }
    for(i=0;i < result.items.length;i++) {

        str = result.items[i].start.dateTime;
        end = result.items[i].end.dateTime;

        eventsList.events.push({
            "title": result.items[i].summary,
            "start": str,
            "end": end,
            "description": result.items[i].description
        });
    }
                    var myEvents = eventsList.events;
                      $('#calendar').fullCalendar({

                      header: {
                        left: 'prev,next today controle',
                        center: 'title',
                        right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
                      },
                      defaultView: 'agendaWeek',
                       timezone: "Europe/Paris",
                      selectable: true,
                      selectHelper: true,
                      minTime:"07:00:00",
                      maxTime:"21:00:00",
                      contentHeight: 685, 
                      lang: 'fr',
                      select: function(start, end) {
                        var title = prompt('Event Title:');
                        var eventData;

                        if (title) {
                          eventData = {
                            title: title,
                            start: start,
                            end: end,
                            description: description
                          };
                          $('#calendar').fullCalendar('renderEvent', eventData, true); // stick? = true
                        }
                        $('#calendar').fullCalendar('unselect');
                      },
                      editable: true,
                      eventLimit: true, // allow "more" link when too many events
                      events: myEvents

                    });

                setTimeout("$('.fc-today-button').click();", 50);
    });
})();
```

Comment: Hey, I'm sorry, I don't think I understand how that solves my problem, would you mind explaining?

Comment: First, I request to Google the content of the calendar (doRequest), then I parse it and finally I pass the variable "myEvent" to the fullCalendar. If you replace your id and your key in the jsfiddle, does your event appear ? Or is it still blank ?

Comment: It's still blank. With your code I can't even get the calendar to show.

Comment: I updated my answer, if you want to take a look!
Thank you